# Using SVN with Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I decided to give LibGDX a try and am planning to use SVN for my code repository. I created my LibGDX project via the Gradle build as outlined in the book "Learning LibGDX Game Development". I'm not quite sure how to add the project to my repository. I have tried to upload the root folder (Project below) into svn, which does contain all the sub-project, but when I check out my workspace only contains the Project folder.

Below is the structure of the project in Eclipse after the gradle build.

1. Project
2. Project-android
3. Project-core
4. Project-desktop
5. Project-html
6. Project-ios

After checking out from svn

1. Project

Has anyone used SVN with LibGDX, if yes can you please guide on how to add a project to repo and checkout correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, hope this helps someone someday :)

1. Using the normal LibGDX approach, create a project using File -> Import -> Gradle (gradle build).
2. Highlight all of the project folders and right click -> team -> share project
3. Note: SVN does not support adding multiple folders at once, make sure to click 'Share Project' option.
4. Enter repo URL: (I just clicked Next)
5. Enter folder name: (I used 'Use project name as folder name')
6. Click finish
7. Repeat for each project folder

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but it accomplished what I am trying to do.